# React-sortable-hoc with formData

Tags: reactjs, jquery-ui-sortable

In my case, I would like to develop a sortable form list. Unfortunately, the state of form is not updated after sorting. Please help. I stuck at this for a week.

I am sorry that i do not know how to import the 'react-sortable-hoc' library to the follow JSFiddle.

link: https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {SortableContainer, SortableElement, arrayMove} from 'react-sortable-hoc';

class ElementItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: this.props.value
        }

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text" name="value" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
        )
    }
}

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) =>
  <li><ElementItem value={value}/></li>
);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((value, index) => (
      var key = 'item-' + index;
        <SortableItem key={key} index={index} value={value} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});

export default class SortableComponent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: Array.apply(null, Array(100)).map((val, index) => 'Item ' + index)
        }
    }
    onSortEnd({oldIndex, newIndex}) {
        this.setState({
            items: arrayMove(this.state.items, oldIndex, newIndex)
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd.bind(this)} helperClass="SortableHelper" />
        )
    }
}

render(<SortableComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-sortable-hoc/dist/umd/react-sortable-hoc.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few typos in your code. After fixing them and changing this

```
  {items.map((value, index) => (
  var key = 'item-' + index;
    <SortableItem key={key} index={index} value={value} />
  ))}
```

to this:

```
  {items.map((value, index) => {
    var key = 'item-' + value;
    return (<SortableItem key={key} index={index} value={value} />)
  })}
```

everything works as expected. Unfortunately, I'm not sure why this really helps - because of some issues in react-sortable-hoc or because react keys are not updated properly, but it works

Here's the working pen with solution applied: https://codepen.io/evgen/pen/KqmKjK

Comment: I do not know why. I need to add ComponentWillReceiveProps() and componentWillUpdate() at the ElementItem for updating the parent state and the child props to achieve the purpose. But it is trouble, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

It actually has to do with what key you are passing to the Form.

If you change `var key = 'item-' + index;` to `var key = 'item-' + value;`
you are set to go.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this issue, my suggestion is also the key prop. As mentioned, don't set it to index, because index is changing on drag and drop.

My suggestion is to also not set it to value because value is the entire form and that is also subject to change. Set key to a unique ID (perhaps the form name from redux-form, if you're using that).

Having this information would have saved me two days of frustration.